# ReactJS: State is not changing

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
class Checkbox extends React.Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      checked: true
    }
  }
  changeClick()  {
    this.setState({checked: !this.state.checked})
  }
  render() {
    var chk;
    if(this.state.checked){
      chk='Checked';
    }else{
      chk='Unchecked'
    }
    return (
       <div>
         <h2>Checkbox is {chk}</h2>
         <input type='checkbox' onChange={this.changeClick} defaultChecked=
         {this.state.checked}/>
      </div>
  )
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(
  <Checkbox />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

I'm new to React and trying to learn ES2015 too, can somebody help me with this, why State is not changing in this snippet.

Any help would be appreciated thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use an anonymous function to bind `this`

```
  changeClick = () =>  {
    this.setState((prevState)=>{return {checked:!prevState.checked}})
  }
```

Also, check the console in the browser to see errors. Then you can search for answers to the error, this is a very common one.

Edit: updated based on comment

Comment: You can read in the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate) that its not good idea to manipulate the state based on current state in that way,because calling set state is asynchronous.You should use updater callback.`setState((prevState)=>{return {checked:!prevState.checked}})`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is due to unavailability of `this` inside `changeClick()`. this is *undefined* inside the function. to avoid this you can bind this  method inside the constructor

```
this.changeClick = this.changeClick.bind(this);
```

or

Use es6 arrow functions

```
changeClick = () =>  {
    this.setState({checked: !this.state.checked})
  }
```

see the fiddle given below
https://jsfiddle.net/yxzyp7yq/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=yxzyp7yq

Comment: I prefer arrow functions